# RegEx: Searching for numbers (int, float) that are NOT part of a word

Tags: regex, search, vertica

I'm hoping we have some regular expression guru's here that might be able to help me - a regex newbie - solve a problem.

I know some people will want to know some background info on this issue:

Regex Flavor: Basic Regex, being used in a Vertica Database using the REGEXP_REPLACE function.

The regex I am using is working great with one exception.

I have a rule that I'm trying to implement, related to stripping the numbers from text, where any number that is part of a word, e.g. table5, go2market, 33monroe, room222, etc. is ignored and NOT filtered.

Here is what I started with for detecting numbers:

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]
```

That seems to work pretty well, including handling directly adjacent commas and parentheses for example.

But all cases where there is a number that is part of alphabetic text is also being detected, which fails the rule that it cannot be a part of a word, and by word, I mean any alphabetic text.

So, in searching for solutions, I happened upon this regex that seems to work well detecting those specific cases where numbers appear next to, or in, any string of characters:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```

My thought was that maybe I could add this as an INVERTED match to my original regex, to allow it to still select standalone numbers while ignoring those that were a part of a word, like so:

```
[-+]?[0-9]^((?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*\.?[0-9]^((?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```

Unfortunately however, it breaks the original detection of standalone numbers.
:(

I'm hoping there is someone here that can spot what I'm doing wrong, and help me identify the right solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must add the tag for the language or tool you use for any regex question since there are different kinds of regex flavours.

Comment: What about the case of something like `table5.5`? Do you want `.5` to be replaced or no?

Comment: @casimirethippolyte, I am using Vertica, which I did tag in my posting.  Someone else suggested the regex flavor is based on Perl, however it does not appear to support all Perl language constructs, so I'm not sure what other "language or tool" I could add, other than perhaps SQL?  Would that qualify?

Comment: @ctwheels, Given the rules, table5 would be rejected, but since the column name indicated "5" (following the period) is standalone, I would think it would be accepted.  However, that being said, I would be fine if it were rejected as part of the "word" table5.5.  :)

Comment: Many regex flavors are more or less based on Perl, that is why I think adding the perl tag isn't a very useful. The vertica tag suffices in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Vertica documentation, the regex flavour seems to follow the Perl syntax. In this case you can use negative lookarounds and in particular a negative lookbehind: `(?<!\w)` *(not preceded with a word character.)*

Lookarounds are only tests and don't consume characters.

You can also use a negative lookahead to test the right part, `(?!\w)` *(not followed by a word character)*, but it's more simple to use a word boundary since the pattern ends with a digit *(that is also a word character)*:

```
(?<!\w)[-+]?\d*\.?\d+\b
```

In the worst case, if you have something like `v1.0` in your string and you want to avoid it, you can try to use the bactracking control verbs `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)`. `(*FAIL)` forces the pattern to fail and `(*SKIP)` skips all the already matched positions before it. I hope vertica supports these Perl regex features.

Something like:

```
\p{L}+[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(*SKIP)(?!\p{L})
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the second regex seems to ignore cases where numbers exist between parentheses, regardless of whether comma's are there or not, e.g.: "numeric(18,0)" or "bytes=1048576 )".  The shorter version seemed to do a better job of  accomplishing the goal of detecting numbers, except when part of a word.  Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: @Bjorn: sorry the second pattern was wrong. It is corrected now.